# Vision Framework (iOS): How are VNDetectFaceLandmarksRequest and VNDetectFaceRectanglesRequest different?

Tags: ios, swift, machine-learning, face-detection, vision

There are two different requests that you can use for face detection tasks with the iOS Vision Framework: `VNDetectFaceLandmarksRequest` and `VNDetectFaceRectanglesRequest`. Both of them return an array of `VNFaceObservation`, one for each detected face. `VNFaceObservation` has a variety of optional properties, including `boundingBox` and `landmarks`. The landmarks object then also includes optional properties like `nose`, `innerLips`, `leftEye`, etc.

Do the two different Vision requests differ in how they perform face detection?

It seems that `VNDetectFaceRectanglesRequest` only finds a bounding box (and maybe some other properties), but does not find any landmarks. On the other hand, `VNDetectFaceLandmarksRequest` seems to find both, bounding box and landmarks.
Are there cases where one request type will find a face and the other one will not? Is `VNDetectFaceLandmarksRequest` **superior** to `VNDetectFaceRectanglesRequest`, or does the latter maybe have advantages in **performance** or **reliability**?

Here is an example code of how these two Vision requests can be used:

```
let faceLandmarkRequest = VNDetectFaceLandmarksRequest()
let faceRectangleRequest = VNDetectFaceRectanglesRequest()
let requestHandler = VNImageRequestHandler(ciImage: image, options: [:])
try requestHandler.perform([faceRectangleRequest, faceLandmarkRequest])
if let rectangleResults = faceRectangleRequest.results as? [VNFaceObservation] {
    let boundingBox1 = rectangleResults.first?.boundingBox   //this is an optional type
}
if let landmarkResults = faceLandmarkRequest.results as? [VNFaceObservation] {
    let boundingBox2 = landmarkResults.first?.boundingBox   //this is an optional type
    let landmarks = landmarkResults.first?.landmarks   //this is an optional type
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- `VNDetectFaceRectanglesRequest` is a more lightweight operation for finding face rectangle
- `VNDetectFaceLandmarksRequest` is a heavier operation, which can also help locate landmarks on the face